# Control position/placement of jsf.js.jsf?ln=javax.faces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Is it possible to control where in your head the "jsf.js.jsf?ln=javax.faces" line gets inserted?  My JSF page currently renders like so:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/wfmportal/javax.faces.resource/theme.css.jsf?ln=primefaces-aristo" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/wfmportal/javax.faces.resource/jsf.js.jsf?ln=javax.faces"></script>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/wfmportal/styles/menuStyleIE6.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/wfmportal/styles/style.css?v=1.0" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/wfmportal/javascript/jquery-1.5.1.min1.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/wfmportal/javascript/app-combined-min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
```

... but I would like to call the CSS files first, followed by the JavaScript.  So, something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <!-- All CSS -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/wfmportal/javax.faces.resource/theme.css.jsf?ln=primefaces-aristo" />
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/wfmportal/styles/menuStyleIE6.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/wfmportal/styles/style.css?v=1.0" media="screen" />

    <!-- All JS-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/wfmportal/javax.faces.resource/jsf.js.jsf?ln=javax.faces"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/wfmportal/javascript/jquery-1.5.1.min1.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/wfmportal/javascript/app-combined-min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
```

My app is written using JSF 2.0.11 (Mojarra) and PrimeFaces 3.4.2.

Comment: That's doable with a custom `ResourceHandler`. And even more. An open source example can be found here:  http://showcase.omnifaces.org/resourcehandlers/CombinedResourceHandler

Comment: By the way, JSF 2.0.11? You mean Mojarra 2.0.11? That's over 3 years old already. I'd really consider moving on to latest 2.1 or perhaps 2.2 if your environment is Servlet 3.0 capable.

Comment: Thanks BalusC.  Yes, I meant Mojarra (I've edited question to reflect this).  Unfortunately the company I'm with now moves very slowly.  Most of their apps still run on JSF 1.1 / WebLogic 10.2.  I'm "fortunate" in that my current project/app runs on WebLogix 10.3.5, which being a Servlet 2.5 container gives me the luxury of using JSF 2.0, bot not higher.